# Younger audiences and chat

Tags: community-management

Most multiplayer games have some sort of way to communicate. It is usually verbal, written, or emotive gestures.

If I were to allow young children, from 11 to 13, access to a game I'm creating where anyone can type anything, what would I need to do?

The things I can think of are; hide all chat, only allow other young players to talk to each other with a list of censored words, or just allow predetermined sentences and actions to be used.

Comment: If you want to allow freeform chatting -- apply a filter.  If you want to use predetermined sentences, use pre-determined sentences.  These are two totally different design choices, and we cannot make that decision for you.

Comment: For the free form chat, you may want to consider some form of parental control/supervision. From a simple report of contacts, and perhaps a way for the parent to white/black list them, to allowing the parent to set the censored words. That is without going into the intrusive disclosure of all chat. Whitelisting contacts allows the parent to ensure the child doesn't chat with strangers. Letting the parent set censored words (to not be transmited or recieved) will also prevent the children to disclosure their personal information to strangers.

Comment: In the US, you'd have to comply with [COPPA](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule) rules

Comment: Was just adding a COPPA comment myself. Also note, the [EU is working on similar laws](http://www.coppalawattorney.com/the-eu-to-adopt-coppa-framework-in-2016/).

Answer (score 2):

Legally, you "just" need to comply with the appropriate child protection laws in your jurisdictions (you probably want to discuss this aspect of the issue with a lawyer). Although I put "just" in quotes because that might be a lot of work.

In the United States, for example, you have [COPPA](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/rules/rulemaking-regulatory-reform-proceedings/childrens-online-privacy-protection-rule) (among potentially other things), which basically means you can't collect personal information about a child without permission from a guardian. The bookkeeping involved there is so tedious that most organizations simply put a clause in their EULA to deny the service to under-13-year-olds (including [StackExchange](http://stackexchange.com/legal)).

From another standpoint, you probably want to protect yourself from potentially-bad PR that might result from a story about a child being verbally harassed or otherwise exposed to something unsavory via interaction with other users of your game - regardless of whether or not you agree with that position on moral or ethical or whatever grounds.

A typical way to do this is to design you game to simply limit the range of expressible interaction that's possible with other players. Not just for young players, for *all* players (otherwise players are incentivized to lie about their age once they realize they are "missing" features of the game). Reducing interactions to a set of predetermined emotes or icon bubbles is a great way to handle this, and as a bonus may make it easier to port your game to consoles or other platforms where a keyboard is not a common input device.

Parental control options, as noted in the comments of your question, are another good idea, although not something particularly common. For young kids in the age range you're talking about, however, it's still likely that the parents are the ones actually purchasing and setting up the game and so it might be an avenue worth investigating if the "icon emotes" approach isn't what you're after. You can implement a range of options. Offhand, the ones I think might be useful are:

- disabling chat entirely
- disabling private messaging
- disabling or requiring confirmation of friendship requests
- a mode where customizations of other avatars (if possible in your game) isn't rendered; everybody appears in generic or default outfits
- two-factor-ish login approaches, where the parent must confirm a child's attempt to start the game